# Sort Data in Mysql With Condition

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I Write the following python code but I have a problem. I need to set a condition for MySQL 'if two var in column height is equal display more width one upper':
[image]

````
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="",
  database="data"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY Height"

mycursor.execute(sql)

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()


for x in myresult:
    print(x[0],x[1],x[2],'\n')```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the second condition for order  by

```
SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY Height, width
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY Height, width DESC
```

for descending order of width with same height